# Implementing a linked list in Java (Finding/Deleting Nodes)

Tags: java, linked-list

I've been working on some code to implement an (edit: *unidirectional*) linked list in java. My main issue is coming about when it comes to finding and deleting nodes, that is, using Find(data) tells the user whether or not a node is present in the list; Delete(data) actually removes the node from the list after it is found (or does nothing if the node isn't found). Find(data) and Delete(data) use the same if-else logic, so for right now I just copied the code from the Find method into the delete method, with appropriate pointers in the delete method to "hop over" the deleted node.

I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way of doing this. I thought of using booleans in the delete block, for example:

```
public void Delete(data)
{
    if Find(data) 
    { 
        //code to delete node
    }
}
```

but because the current node could be at the head, tail, or somewhere in the middle, you'd still have to have the loop logic to check where you are so you can set the appropriate references. For example, if the user wants to delete the node at the tail, then the previous node's next node would be set to null. However, in the middle, you'd have to run a while loop to iterate through the list, i.e.

```
while (iter.NextNode !=null)
        {
            if (iter.NextNode.data == data)
            {
                iter.NextNode = iter.NextNode.NextNode;
                System.out.println(data + " was found in the list and removed"

                break;

            }
            else if (iter.NextNode.NextNode == null && iter.NextNode.data == data) 
            {//this is kinda weird. I couldn't use an else block, because either 
             //the code would never exit the loop, or it would keep running
                iter.NextNode = null;
                System.out.println(data + " was found in the list and removed. ");
                break;
            }

        iter = iter.NextNode;

        if (node.NextNode == null && node.data != data) 
        {//i guess I could have just put this if statement inside
         //the else block
            System.out.println(data + " was not found in the list.");
            break;
        }


        }
```

The above code block handles both cases.

The below code block is my Find(data) method:

```
public void Find(int data)
{
    Node node = head;
    if (head == null)
    {
        System.out.println("No nodes found. ");

    }


    else if (node.NextNode==null)
    {
        if (node.data == data)
        {
            System.out.println( data + " was found in the list.");

        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("That value was not found in the list.");

        }
    }
    else
    {
        while (node.NextNode !=null)
        {
            if (node.data == data)
            {
                System.out.println(data + " was found in the list.");
                break;

            }
            else if (node.NextNode.NextNode == null && node.NextNode.data == data)
            {
                System.out.println(data + " was found in the list.");
                break;
            }
            else    
            {
                node = node.NextNode;
            }
            if (node.NextNode == null && node.data != data)
            {
                System.out.println(data + " was not found in the list.");
                break;
            }
        }

    }
```

}

In case the question wasn't clear: Is there a way I can use my Find(data) method in the delete block, and take out all the logic?

Thanks for your guidance. I really appreciate it!

Comment: The logic behind the find and delete methods is not the same.  In delete, you need a pointer to the node _previous_ to being deleted.  However, your find method would likely only be returning the node which has been found.

Comment: Why does your `Find(int data)` method return nothing? Should it not return a reference to the found `Node`?

Comment: @JonnyHenly Even if he does this, it won't necessarily help in deletion, because he would need the _previous_ node as well, assuming his list is unidirectional.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You're correct, I assumed a doubly linked list. However OP's `Find(int data)`, if public, should return at least a `boolean` if not a `Node`...

Comment: I apologize, the text and the code I posted are not consistent. When I say "previous" node, I really mean the current node, since I can delete node.next by saying node.next = node.next.next;

In the above, I was saying boolean, but I ran into problems trying to implement it, so I changed the return type of Find(data) to void when I posted the question.

Again, sorry for the confusion.

Also, yes, this is a uni-directional linked list, and a clarification of that has been made above.

Comment: Andy, when you delete a node from a unidirectional linked list, you need to _splice_ it out, meaning that you say `previous.NextNode = curr.NextNode`.  Does this make sense?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen This is exactly what I've done! Only I use node to refer to the previous node, and node.NextNode to refer to the current node (confusing, I know, but it made sense when I was writing it) The program has no trouble compiling and everything works as it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your Find() method returns nothing, you can not use it in a Delete() method.
To Centralize your code for Find() and Delete() create another private method - getPreviousNode(int data) which returns previous node of a required node.

```
private Node getPreviousNode(int data) {
    Node iter = head;

    while (iter.NextNode != null) {
        if (iter.NextNode.data == data) {
            return iter;
        }

        iter.nextNode = iter.nextNode.nextNode;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Call this method in both Find() and Delete() method.

```
void Find(int data) {
    // Code to handle head & tail conditions

    Node prevNode = getPreviousNode(data);

    if (prevNode != null) {
        System.out.println("Found");
    }

    ...
}

void Delete(int data) {
    // Code to handle head & tail conditions

    Node prevNode = getPreviousNode(data);

    if (prevNode != null) {
        Node node = prevNode.nextNode;
        prevNode.nextNode = node.nextNode;
        node.nextNode = null;
        System.out.println("Found & Deleted");
    }

    ...
}
```

---

Answer to your comment:
Writing just "prevNode.nextNode = prevNode.NextNode.NextNode" is not sufficient.

Consider Following LinkedList:

> A[data = 1 | nextNode = b] --> B[data = 4 | nextNode = c] --> C[data = 55 | nextNode = null]

where,
A, B, C : Nodes
a, b, c  : References to Nodes A, B and C respectively.

B : Node to delete

Now consider a code to delete node:

```
Node prevNode = getPreviousNode(data);
```

> prevNode = a; // "a" is a reference to Node A returned by getPreviousNode(4)

```
if (prevNode != null) 
  node = prevNode.nextNode;
```

> node = b; // prevNode.nextNode is 'b'

```
  prevNode.nextNode = node.nextNode;
```

> prev.NextNode = c; // node.nextNode is 'c'

Now LinkedList is:

> A[data = 1 | nextNode = c]     B[data = 4 | nextNode = c] --> C[data = 55 | nextNode = null]

Now node A has a reference of Node C as a nextNode. So Node B is unlinked from LinkedList 
but not completely removed from LinkedList because Node B is still having reference of Node C 
as a NextNode. So you must remove this reference to remove Node B completely from LinkedList.

So following statement is neccessary

```
node.nextNode = null;
```

Now LinkedList is:

> A[data = 1 | nextNode = c] --> C[data = 55 | nextNode = null] 
>  
>   B[data = 4 | nextNode = null] is removed from LinkedList.

Comment: Couldn't I just say:

prevNode.nextNode = prevNode.NextNode.NextNode?

Comment: With your statement in a comment you are changing a reference of a previous node(prevNode) from required node(a node to delete) to next node. But required node is still having a reference of a next node. So it is still connected with your LinkedList. So statement "node.nextNode = null" is required to completely remove node from a List. After this statement you can make "node = null", so all the references to required node will be deleted.

Comment: Also, `getPrevious` modifies `iter.nextNode`, which I'm sure you don't intend

Answer (score 0):

You could share `findPrevious` as @SanjayChavan suggests, but when you are practiced at writing linked list code, you find that it's already clean and sharing `findPrevious` doesn't make it better:

```
boolean Delete(int data)
{
    Node prev = null, node = null;
    for (node = head; node!=null; node=(prev=node).nextNode)
    {
        if (node.data == data)
        {
            if (prev!=null)
                prev.nextNode = node.nextNode;
            else
                head = node.nextNode;
            node.nextNode = null;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false; 
}

Node Find(int data)
{
    for (Node node = head; node != null; node = node.nextNode)
    {
        if (node.data==data)
            return node;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Once Sanjay's code is fixed so that it can find and delete the `head` node, it will be longer and more complicated than this.

Answer (score 0):

```
   public static ListNode search( List list, int target )
   {
      ListNode cursor = list.getFirst( );

      while( cursor != null )
      {
         if( cursor.getInfo( ) == target )
            return cursor;

         cursor = cursor.getLink( );
      }

      return cursor;
   }

   public void remove( int element )
   {
      ListNode cursor;
      ListNode target = search( this, element );

      if( isEmpty( ) )
         System.out.println( "There are no elements in this list." );

      if( target == null )
         System.out.println( element+" is not in this list." );
      else
      {
         if( head.getInfo( ) == element )
         {
            if( head.getLink( ) == null )
               head = null;
            else if( head == tail )
               tail = null;
            else
               head = head.getLink( );
         }
         else if( tail.getInfo( ) == element )
         { 
            for( cursor = head; cursor.getLink( ).getInfo( ) != element; cursor = cursor.getLink( ) )
            { }

            cursor.setLink( null );
            tail = cursor;
         }
         else
         {
            for( cursor = head; cursor.getLink( ).getInfo( ) != element; cursor = cursor.getLink( ) )
            { }

            cursor.setLink( cursor.getLink( ).getLink( ) );
         }
      }
   }
```